# How to change user account settings with lxde

Tags: lxde, users

How can I change my user account settings using ubuntu 12.04 and lxde? Up to now, I always have to log in manually, which I'd like to avoid. Yet, I'm unable to find the corresponding sub-menu.

Kind regards,

schlossblick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get Users and Groups under LXDE, you have to install Gnome System Tools.  To do that

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

[image]

[image]